# Android align textview to right

Tags: android, xml, textview, alignment

in Android XML I am try to set the alignment of the text to right:

```
android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
```

I also align it in the center of the parent, hence the center add in. Now I have the text on a right alignment but I want to assign it to the position of the parents left:

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

But this only keeps the alignment of the text and does not align to the parents center?
Heres the entire view xml code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_example"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textColor="#474747"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Can someone help me create a solution for having the textview's text aligned to the right but be assigned to the parents left?

Comment: Could you please show the whole xml and make a drawing how it is and how it should look? This would help me a lot to understand your problem

Comment: Is your `TextView` within a `LinearLayout` or a `RelativeLayout`? `android:gravity` is for use on elements within a `LinearLayout`; `android:layout_alignParentLeft` is for use on elements within a `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually ur code is working but it will be clear if you give width less than parent, try this change

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_example"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:textColor="#474747"
        android:text="ABAGSADGDBAJDHADNA"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this....

```
       <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#E6F2B2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="end|center"
                android:text="@string/title"
                android:textColor="#323232"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
```